# How to add more more widgets on screen in flutter, after user action

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want the text fields of this form to appear on the screen one by one, as the user submits the data. 
For e.g., as is shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: can you include your tested widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** using list

```dart
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [TextEditingController()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
            controllers.length,
            (index) => TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: controllers[index],
              onSubmitted: (v) {
                controllers.add(TextEditingController());
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can create a `bool` on state and use it to control visibility of email `TextFiled`

```dart
 bool showEmailField = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onSubmitted: (value) {
              print("call Next one");
              setState(() {
                showEmailField = true;
              });
            },
          ),
          if (showEmailField) TextField(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

For animation, you can use `ScaleTransition`. For more widgets, you can create list and use conditional state to generate widgets under build method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate the time and effort you put in this Yeasin❤️. But is there a way to **put a new Text Widget**, just next to the text widget in focus.. (once the user submits, or presses enter to go to new line)  \n

this would have been very simple, if it was the case of javascript... But I am new to flutter, And still learning about it's different features...

p.s., I checked out your answers on flutter, and I really appreciate the skill and work your put in this.

Comment: Yes it is possible in that case, you need to take care of retrieving Text using generated `TextEditingController`, I think it might be better to create list of widget then showing them using conditional state. Do you want to generate new `TextFiled ` on every `onsubmit`  or just make it visible?

Comment: Can you test update answer,

Comment: you are missing `MaterialApp`   `void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));`

Comment: It says - **Request failed with status code 500**

Comment: Can you test this on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e41d64e7c16018cac4bb73a348500543)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm thankful for your answers ❤️... But how do I get it to work on Android Devices.

Comment: Do you get any errors after using this snippet on android device?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KmcHFs1X ⬅️ Here you go

Comment: You need to remove `import 'dart:html';`

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add `multiDexEnabled true` in **build.gradle** in my case.  Your help means a lot, I couldn't had done this without you. ❤️